# Business days in Django

Tags: django, date, django-models

I need to implement a conditional break which uses business days. I have a class with a `DateField`, and if that date is less than 5 business days in the future, something (action `a`) happens, else `b` happens. How can I determine the number of business days between two objects?

Obviously I'll need to calculate what 5 business days from today is. Finding 5 days in the future would be easy, using a simple time-delta, but to account for business days, it gets more complicated. I think I can safely ignore holidays for now (it's not the best case, but I think I can make due with just having Business days be Monday-Friday). Can anyone give me some guidance as to how I could do something like: `target = today + 5 business_days`?

Thanks

Comment: If you're not counting holidays, and you're always counting five business days, isn't that just one calendar week each time?  Five business days from Monday is next Monday, etc.

Comment: Oh god... of course it is...

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper - Only if the starting date is also a business day

Comment: In this case I can pretty much guarantee it will be.

Comment: Then yep, add 7 days and you're all set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a generic solution, even though your case is embarrassingly simple ;P

```
from datetime import timedelta, date

def add_business_days(from_date, number_of_days):
    to_date = from_date
    while number_of_days:
       to_date += timedelta(1)
       if to_date.weekday() < 5: # i.e. is not saturday or sunday
           number_of_days -= 1
    return to_date
```

And the result.

```
>>> date.today()
datetime.date(2013, 7, 25)
>>> add_business_days(date.today(), 6)
datetime.date(2013, 8, 2)
```

Bonus marks if you check whether a date falls on a holiday in the if statement.

Comment: Thanks! I'll accept this answer, but I'd say it was so simple to not even warrant one. I feel incredibly dumb for not coming up with that on my own.

Comment: "Only if the starting date is also a business day" "In this case I can pretty much guarantee it will be." Can you actually guarantee this? If not, you may end up using this code after all.

Answer (score 0):

**This Example is when you are making a django project as an API**

You can get business days with  [Numpy](http://www.numpy.org/) which uses [SCIPY](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.datetime.html)(check for more details)
You will have to install `numpy` through `pip`

Python 2.7

`pip install numpy`

Python 3

`pip3 install numpy`

In `models.py` add depending on where you want to put your property method :

```
class WorkingDay(models.Model):
    # YY-MM-DD
    start = models.DateField(null=True, verbose_name="start")
    end = models.DateField(null=True, verbose_name="end")
@property
def workdays(self):

    total = np.busday_count(self.start, self.end)

    return total
```

Then in your `serializers.py` you might have something like this.

```
class WorkingDaySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    workdays = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = WorkingDay
        fields = '__all__'
        read_only_fields = ['workdays']
```

In your views you might do something like this.

```
class WorkingDayAPI(APIView):

    """
    {   "start":"2018-01-01",
        "end":"2018-05-01"
    }
    GET work days between dates 
    """

    serializer_class = WorkingDaySerializer

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        business_days = WorkingDay.objects.all()
        serializer = WorkingDaySerializer(business_days, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        start = request.data.get('start')
        end = request.data.get('end')

        # bizdays = request.data.get('bizdays')

        business_days = WorkingDay.objects.create(**request.data)
        business_days.start = start
        business_days.end = end
        business_days.workdays = workdays
        business_days.save()
        serializer = WorkingDaySerializer(business_days)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```